# Capturar valor de fila de tabla html en model y mostrar en textbox asp.net

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Quisiera poder tomar el valor de una celda al hacer click sobre la fila en una tabla html y que ese valor quede en el text de un textbox.

La tabla se abre en un modal de Jquery (bootstrap) y el textbox está en la pagina principal.
Tengo éste código:

````
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CIE10</th>
            <th>Diagnóstico</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <td>C796</td>
            <td>Neoplasia maligna secundaria de ovario izquierdo</td>
                                                                
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>C509</td>
            <td>Neoplasia maligna secundaria de parte no especificada del sistema nervioso</td>
                                                                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>```

El modal es éste:
````

```

El botón es:
[image: Botón pagina principal y el textbox donde debe estar el valor de la tabla]

[image: Al hacer click en la fila, tomar el valor y enviarlo al textbox del diagnóstico anterior]

[image: Aqui debe quedar el valor de la tabal del modal]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Buen día, puedes incluir el código completo de lo que has intentado hacer?

Comment: Traté de usar un script para capturar el valor al hacer click sobre la fila:
`$('#tbDx tr').on('click', function(){
  var dato = $(this).find('td:first').html();
  $('#TBDx').val(dato);
});`

Pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿ummm el codigo de la bodal lo generas dinamicamente?